# Opening Camera UI from Native C# Code(Windows 10)

Tags: windows, cordova, windows-runtime, hybrid-mobile-app

I have the requirement to call a native function in WinRT from cordova javascript.This function should open the CameraUI natively(Using C#).

The restriction is camera cannot be opened using the Camera plugin.It has to be opened from the native code.

The below code is the WinRT component.When it is called (Test.TestController.openCamera();) from the Cordova Javascript it is not opening the camera.However, if I call this from a native windows app this able to open the camera.Is there any solution how to solve this issue.

In Summary Windows Hybrid app(JavaScript) required to call the Native WinRT Component to open the custom camera UI.

namespace Test
{
    public sealed class TestController
    {
        public static async void openCamera()
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("openCamera called");
            Preview preview = new Preview();
            preview.openCam();
        }

```
}

public sealed class Preview
{
    MediaCapture mediaCapture;
    public async void openCam()
    {
        await StartPreviewAsync();
    }
    private async Task StartPreviewAsync()
    {
        try
        {

            CaptureElement preview = new CaptureElement();
            StackPanel stackPanel = new StackPanel { Orientation = Orientation.Vertical };
            preview.Stretch = Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Stretch.UniformToFill;
            preview.Width = 400;
            preview.Height = 650;
            stackPanel.Width = 400;
            stackPanel.Height = 650;
            stackPanel.Children.Add(preview);

            //TODO : Instead of using Windows.Current , need to find a way to get reference of the main application view.
            //Window.Current.Content = stackPanel;

            CoreApplicationView newView = CoreApplication.CreateNewView();
            int newViewId = 0;
            await newView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {

                Window.Current.Content = stackPanel;
                // You have to activate the window in order to show it later.
                Window.Current.Activate();

                newViewId = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Id;
            });
            bool viewShown = await ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsStandaloneAsync(newViewId);


            var _deviceInformation = await GetCameraDeviceInfoAsync(Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Back);

            var settings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings();
            settings.StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Video;
            settings.PhotoCaptureSource = PhotoCaptureSource.VideoPreview;
            settings.AudioDeviceId = "";
            if (_deviceInformation != null)
                settings.VideoDeviceId = _deviceInformation.Id;

            mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();
            await mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(settings);
            mediaCapture.SetPreviewRotation(VideoRotation.Clockwise90Degrees);
            preview.Source = mediaCapture;
            await mediaCapture.StartPreviewAsync();
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            // This will be thrown if the user denied access to the camera in privacy settings
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("The app was denied access to the camera");

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("MediaCapture initialization failed.");
        }
    }


    private static async Task<DeviceInformation> GetCameraDeviceInfoAsync(Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel desiredPanel)
    {

        DeviceInformation device = (await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.VideoCapture))
            .FirstOrDefault(d => d.EnclosureLocation != null && d.EnclosureLocation.Panel == desiredPanel);

        if (device == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "No suitable devices found for the camera of type {0}.", desiredPanel));
        }
        return device;
    }
}
```

}